# Is Protractor or WebDriverJS making sure the statement are executed and completed in order?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I've been reading WebDriverJS control flow and Protractor in:
http://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow, and I am confused of the description:

```
  it('should find an element by text input model', function() {
    browser.get('app/index.html#/form');

    var username = element(by.model('username'));
    username.clear();
    username.sendKeys('Jane Doe');

    var name = element(by.binding('username'));

    expect(name.getText()).toEqual('Jane Doe');

    // Point A
  });
```

It says:

'At Point A, none of the tasks have executed yet. The browser.get call is at the front of the control flow queue, and the name.getText() call is at the back. The value of name.getText() at point A is an unresolved promise object.'

and

'Protractor adapts Jasmine so that each spec automatically waits until the control flow is empty before exiting.'

From the above it seems that WebDriverJS can only guarantee that the statement will be **executed in the order** but not **completed one after another**. Protractor however will do it because **it will wait for previous statement to finish in control flow before executing the next**?

But I also find other descriptions of controlflow:

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise_exports_ControlFlow.html

This says 'The control flow will ensure tasks are executed in the order scheduled, **starting each task only once those before it have completed**'

So which is true? Is control flow doing the job or protractor doing it?